# How to load data into view, in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to register an advertiser. I have the registration working OK but lower in the page I want to record the date/time GMT and the Advertiser's username. And if another user registers that username to go on top, so that past & present advertisers are recorded.

This is the coding I have in the Controller:-

```
$advertiser = $this->input->post('uname');
$data['advertiser'] =  array("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", $advertiser);
$this->load->view('advertising', $data);
```

And this in the view:-

```
<style type="text/css"> .advertiser { position: fixed; width: 100%; left: 11%; top: 50%; } </style>
    <div class="advertiser">
    </div>
```

But that doesn't work. I need help, can anybody?

UPDATE

This is the changed coding in the Controller:-

```
$advertiser = $this->input->post('uname');
$data['advertiser'] =  array(gmdate("d M Y 'T' H:m"), $advertiser);
$this->load->view('advertising', $data);
```

And this is the changed coding in the view:-

```
<style type="text/css"> .advert { position: fixed; width: 100%; left: 11%; top: 38%; } </style>
    <div class="advert"><?php echo (isset($advertiser)) ? $advertiser : ''; ?>
    </div>
```

As a matter of interest if I insert the following into the view I get the gmdate to display, however it doesn't update the time so must be cached.

```
<style type="text/css"> .advert { position: fixed; width: 100%; left: 11%; top: 38%; } </style>
    <div class="advert"><?php echo gmdate("d M Y 'T' H:m") . "<br>"; ?>
    </div>
```

UPDATE

Im getting this error:- Message: Array to string conversion:- It is because of this coding in the view:-

```
<?php echo (isset($advertiser)) ? $advertiser : ''; ?>
```

If I change it to this, I get no result

```
<?php echo (isset($advert)) ? $advertiser : ''; ?>
```

But if I change it to this, I get the result below

```
<?php echo (isset($advertiser)) ? $advert : ''; ?>
```

Message: Undefined variable: advert

I've tried changing the variable in the Controller but it makes no difference.

UPDATE

If I put this in the Controller I get the GMT display:-

```
$data['advertiser'] =  gmdate("d M Y 'T' H:m") ;
```

And if I put this in the Controller I get the username display:-

```
$data['advertiser'] =  $advertiser ;
```

But I cant get them to work together. So there must be something wrong with the array coding.

Comment: Explain better please, we could not understand exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I want to record the GMT at the time of registration, then the users username. Can you explain what you don't understand?

Comment: The key in your `$data` Array gets converted to a variable matching the key name in  the view. e.g. `$data['advertiser']` gets passed into the view as `$advertiser`. The DOM element identifier has nothing to do with this at all since you're just `echo`ing out variables.

Comment: OK, I changed that and it still does not work.

Comment: Maybe if I try with one for example the gmdate or $advertiser, then add the other later. I've already tried that but I'll need your advice on how to do just one.

Comment: `<?php echo (isset($advertiser) ? $advertiser : ''); ?>` should be `<?php echo (isset($advertiser)) ? $advertiser : ''; ?>`. The closing bracket is out of place.

Comment: OK, I changed that but still not work.

Answer (score 0):

You use the Array key name as the variable name in the view.

So you have set `$data['advertiser']` prior and, provided that this value is set correctly and is a String, in your view output the variable where you'd like. I am assuming within `div.advertiser`.

If `$data['advertiser']`'s value is an Array|Object then you will have to dig in and extract to display the child values.

```php
<div class="advertiser">
  <?php echo (isset($advertiser) ? $advertiser : ''; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, I'll try that tomorrow. Its now the end of my day. I was thinking I'll need a "foreach" in the view to cater for any additional advertisers, otherwise it will only record the latest. I'm not yet sure how to code that so maybe you can advise.

Comment: If you have multiple advertisers, then you'll have to set that up in your `$data` Array similar to `$data['advertisers']`. So, yes, you'll need a `foreach` setting the Array and then again in your view to display them all.

Comment: How do I "prior set $data['advertiser']" ?

Comment: I meant that you had already set it before passing to the view.

Comment: Is my coding to obtain GMT correct? I was only guessing. I have the javascript to display GMT but unsure if that works for datetimestamp.

Comment: That should be it's own question detailing the requirements.

Comment: I still cant get this to record. Ive found the correct coding for the GMT. And Ive changed the div name to "advert" and $data['advert']. I had to insert a closing bracket ")" in the view. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost the answer.

The original system that I was attempting will not work, even if I can get the 2 parts to join, because the information would only be available to the user who registers whereas I want the information available to all users.

Therefore I've taken a different approach as follows:-

```
$record = fopen("C:xampp/htdocs/application/views/record.php", "c");
fseek($record, 200) ;
$gm =  gmdate("d M Y H:i T") ;
fwrite($record, $gm);
$up =  (" - $advertiser") . "<br>" ;
fwrite($record, $up);
```

Everything works except it consumes additional bytes which wipes out any previous advertisers. But if I advance previous users by about 35-40 bytes the info displays and moves the previous advertisers closer to the new advertiser. I don't want that to happen.

That appears to be a manufactures fault. I've written to Zend but they are not interested.

Maybe someone here knows of a solution.